# Take the outcome of a draw in ELO formula

Tags: probability, statistics

Is there any way to get the probability of a draw outcome using ELO formula as it only gives the Win probability

ELO formula is given by $E = \frac{1}{1+10^\frac{d}{a}}$ where d is the difference in ELO Rating and a is a constant

Comment: I do not know the formula exactly, but I think that the expectation of points gets into it, not the draw probability itself. But I could be wrong ...

Answer (score 5):

To quote [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system)

> A player's expected score is his probability of winning plus half his
>   probability of drawing. Thus an expected score of 0.75 could represent
>   a 75% chance of winning, 25% chance of losing, and 0% chance of
>   drawing. On the other extreme it could represent a 50% chance of
>   winning, 0% chance of losing, and 50% chance of drawing. The
>   probability of drawing, as opposed to having a decisive result, is not
>   specified in the Elo system. Instead a draw is considered half a win
>   and half a loss.

You could combine Elo predictions with information outside the Elo system about the propensity of draws given different strengths of paired players, but this would be external to the Elo system.  Here is one possible set of distributions, though there are many others and you cannot sensibly choose one without more information.

```
E[score]    P(win)  P(draw) P(lose)
0.0         0.00    0.00    1.00
0.1         0.01    0.18    0.81
0.2         0.04    0.32    0.64
0.3         0.09    0.42    0.49
0.4         0.16    0.48    0.36
0.5         0.25    0.50    0.25
0.6         0.36    0.48    0.16
0.7         0.49    0.42    0.09
0.8         0.64    0.32    0.04
0.9         0.81    0.18    0.01
1.0         1.00    0.00    0.00
```